# Is it possible to echo any variable inside JText::_ if so how

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

Is it possible to print a variable inside the JText

ie:- i need to print $email to test whether it is nil or has value in it...

```
$this->setMessage(JText::_('COM_USERS_REGISTRATION_ACTIVATE_SUCCESS'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JText class has a static method '_' which converts the string argument passed into it into another string, using the language files and settings appropriate for the context. If you want to see what is being passed to setMessage you could just try:

```
echo 'DEBUG setMessage argument: "'.JText::_('COM_USERS_REGISTRATION_ACTIVATE_SUCCESS').'"';
```

If you find that this reveals that _ is returning nothing, then it is likely an indication that there is not an entry for 'COM_USERS_REGISTRATION_ACTIVATE_SUCCESS' in the language file(s) being used.

EDIT:

If you need to append `$email` then just do this:

```
$this->setMessage(JText::_('COM_USERS_REGISTRATION_ACTIVATE_SUCCESS').$email);
```

Comment: no i need to append $email also with it ,so that the out put must be the value inside JText + the email stored in $email

Answer (score 6):

And if you want to use variable in the middle of string or few variables, here's an example for that:

```
$this->setMessage(JText::sprintf('COM_USERS_REGISTRATION_ACTIVATE_SUCCESS', $name, $email);
```

And in language file:

```
COM_USERS_REGISTRATION_ACTIVATE_SUCCESS="Hello %s, your email is: %s"
```

So the final output will look ($name and $email will be replaced by variable values given):

```
Hello $name, your email is: $email
```

Answer (score 0):

`COM_USERS_REGISTRATION_ACTIVATE_SUCCESS` is being replaced by a language definition of the message. If you break that up, Joomla won't recognise it.

You can append variables to that message if you want:

```
$this->setMessage(JText::_('COM_USERS_REGISTRATION_ACTIVATE_SUCCESS') . $email);
```

Or even omit JText if you need to

```
$this->setMessage('some message, email: ' . $email);
```